# Bind list of maps to a table in dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have defined the following data model in dart file:

```dart
 @observable  List alist = toObservable([{'rel':'self', 'name':'John'}, 
   {'rel':'Father', 'name':'tom'},
   {'rel':'Mother', 'name':'jane'}]);
```

and table in html as follows:

```dart
<table id="summaryTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Ralationship to Me</th>          
      <th>Update History</th>
      <th>Remove Relative</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr repeat = "{{p in alist}}">
    <td>
      {{p['name']}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{p['rel']}}
    </td>        
     <td>
      <button on-click="{{updateClicked}}">Update</button>
    </td>
     <td>          
    </td>
  </tr>          
</table>
```

The table is not getting populated. What should be changed?

Comment: Is this within a polymer element? I see no `<template>` tag. Where have you placed the code shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell as you didn't provide much code but at least the `template` is missing in

```dart
<tr template repeat="{{p in alist}}">
```